# Using 0-3 V sensor with 0-10 V PLC

Tags: analog, sensor, input, plc, conversion

I have a sensor that generates an analog 0-3 V output signal. I would like to connect this sensor to a PLC which has only 0-10 V analog inputs.

My questions are:

1. Is this recommended to do in general? I guess that I will lose a lot of resolution (70% of it), and this could affect my application requirements.
2. Is there any other way to add something in between in order to convert the 0-3 V signal to 0-10 V signal?
3. Related with point #1, how do I calculate the resolution of the 0-3V
   signal? my sensor specifications only talk about accuracy but not
   resolution. This is a ph sensor that can measure from 0 to 14 ph,
   and has an accuracy of 0.1. The PLC has 10 bit ADC for the inputs (Arduino Mega based).

The PLC is being feed by a 24 V DC power supply. This power supply has two outputs and one is not being used right now.

Comment: What DC power sources can you use for a converter?

Comment: You need to answer question 1 for yourself.  You should be able to determine if the resolution is adequate for your application.  If it isn't, then you could amplify the signal using an opamp circuit assuming there is a higher voltage available to you (like 12 to 15 V).

Comment: @Andyaka right now I am using a 24V DC power supply with two outputs, one to feed the PLC and one not used. Anyways I have no constraints about power sources so I can add whatever I need.

Comment: @Troutdog I totally agree with the resolution, tomorrow I will do the calculations by myself. Anyways, I think it would be classy to get the better resolution possible and also I have time and resources to do it. Regarding your suggestion about the opamp, it sounds great. I have a 24V DC power supply available for it. What kind of opamp circuit do I need for this? Do you have any documentation about that (mabye an EE stack exchange thread?.

Comment: Is it a DIN mount PLC? If so I would look for a DIN mount analog amplifier with suitable characteristics.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite initially the PLC set up will be on a lab table but probably in the future it will be DIN mount.

Comment: OPAMP:  well, you should be able to find an opamp that will work with 24V.  The most common opamp circuit is an inverting amplifier.  You will have to decide if that works in your application.  For example, the output would be 10V when the input is 0V, and 0V when the input is 3V.  If you don't want that, you can use a non-inverting amplifier topology.  One thing to make note of:  the accuracy will degrade near 0V input due to the nature of opamps.  This can be countered if you have a negative rail  (like -5V) you can use with the opamp.  You can find opamp circuits using a google search.

Comment: In the limit, these OPAMP circuits are just an opamp and a few resistors.  You should also add a bypass cap near the power supply pin to reduce noise.  Something like  
LM7301IM-NS would probably work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No. It's not a good design but if it meets your requirements like this, then there is no need to add a board/module to your setup.
2. I would suggest checking whether the PLC offers an easy fix *(like changing a jumper's position or configuration on the PLC's HMI)* to lower its analog input full scale voltage. If not, then you can amplify the signal using an additional external module.

Comment: Regarding answer #1, I understand, but anywas I would like to add something to get the better resolution possible. Regarding your answer #2, I have check before the PLC and it is not possible to scale the voltage. What kind of modules do you recommend to amplify the signal?.

Comment: Is this a proper installation or just playing in the lab? Did you check if the PLC manufacturer offers external modules for this purpose? What supply voltages do you have around? How do you intend to mount this module it in your setup?

Comment: right now it is just playing in the lab. The manufacturer does not offer external modules but it is an Arduino based PLC. I have a 24V DC power supply available but I could have others if needed. Also the type of mounting is not a constraint. Could you point out a proper type of module for this?

Comment: I found a few modules on Google. They're mostly based on the LM358 op amp. They are cheap (3-5$) and the supply voltage can up to 32V or so, you can also change the gain via the fitted potentiometer. Use the "LM358 module" keywords as an example then **check all the details** of that specific product on your prefered website. EDIT: I don't your PLC's or your target precisions. It's up to you to decide if this combination works.

Comment: that is very useful! I will try it and come back here to write the results.